# Problem about ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: ""

Tags: erc-20

```
// contracts/OurToken.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract OurToken is ERC20 {
constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20("tkname", "tkn") {
    _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
    }
 }
```

this are my helpful-scripts py

```
dependencies:
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.2.0
compiler:
  solc:
    remappinigs:
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.2.0'
dotenv: .env
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

error
ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "".
--> contracts/OurToken.sol:5:1:
|
5 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 1):

seems like you are simply just missing to install the OpenZeppelin library in your project. To fix the issue, you can simply run the following command

```sh
npm install @openzeppelin/contracts
```

Try to check whether you can find any `@openzeppelin` folder under `node_modules`. If there is, then the import should not fail.

Hope this helps~

Answer (score 0):

## Brownie Solution

You can double check that the package is installed using `brownie pm list`. The output will look something like this:

```
OpenZeppelin
 ├─OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.2.0
```

If its not installed, you can run the following command in the terminal:

```
brownie pm install OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.2.0
```

Read more about the package manager command [here](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/package-manager.html).